# Can't ping default gateway on ubuntu 18.0

Tags: ubuntu, ping, gateway

I can't ping my default gateway on ubuntu 18.04.
Below are the output of my settings:

## ifconfig

```
enp12s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.149.90  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 172.30.149.95

        ether f0:1f:af:3e:73:a3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2005  bytes 154598 (154.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 380  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 950  bytes 117982 (117.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 31843  bytes 1932467 (1.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31843  bytes 1932467 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

## route -n

```
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.30.149.94   0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 enp12s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp12s0
172.30.149.80   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     100    0        0 enp12s0
```

## ping 172.30.149.94

```
PING 172.30.149.94 (172.30.149.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.30.149.90 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.30.149.90 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.30.149.90 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 172.30.149.94 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4080ms
```

## cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

## dhclient -v enp12s0

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
...
Listening on LPF/enp12s0/f0:1f:af:3e:73:a3
Sending on   LPF/enp12s0/f0:1f:af:3e:73:a3
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x2d28ac1e)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp12s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5 (xid=0x2d28ac1e)
```

## arp -na

```
? (172.30.149.92) à <incomplet> sur enp12s0
? (172.30.149.94) à <incomplet> sur enp12s0
```

## ip neighbor show

```
172.30.149.92 dev enp12s0  FAILED
172.30.149.94 dev enp12s0  FAILED
```

## iptables -L -v -n

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6000 packets, 368K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6010 packets, 369K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination
```

## cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by     resolvconf(8)
..
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual     nameservers.
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

## ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group  default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp12s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP 
group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:1f:af:3e:73:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.149.90/28 brd 172.30.149.95 scope global noprefixroute     enp12s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group     default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:18:8b:70:10:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

## sysctl -p

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

## iptables -t nat -L -v -n

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                       destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               >destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                   destination
```

## telnet 172.30.149.94 22

```
Trying 172.30.149.94...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

## telnet 172.30.149.94 80

```
Trying 172.30.149.94...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

## cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

## iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

## tcpdump -v arp

```
tcpdump: listening on enp12s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:44:09.289931 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:10.314067 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:14.021038 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 62.201.153.150 tell 62.201.153.145, length 46
13:44:14.021065 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 62.201.153.142 tell 62.201.153.137, length 46
13:44:14.409927 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:15.433950 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:16.457979 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:17.481925 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:18.505913 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:19.021013 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 62.201.153.142 tell 62.201.153.137, length 46
```

Comment: You can't ping it but .... 1/ Does it forward the traffic like expected ? 2/ Is it supposed to be ping-able ? Could you try `hping3 -S -p 22 <your gw>` (it's a TCP ping to port 22 with SYN flag set) and edit your answer to put the result ?

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply. Unfortunately, this command hping3 is not installed on my ubuntu and can't install for the moment. is there another way to check it?

Comment: A small capture with tcpdump maybe usefull, but pretty sure it won't help much.... `iptables -L -v -n` and `iptables -t nat -L -v -n` could help. Also, can you try just a `telnet <your gw>` to port 22 or 80. Another strange thing is that you have packets on the RX counter (so the link is physically OK) ... but you have RX **dropped** packet.

Comment: could you please try `tcpdump -v arp`, then ping the gateway again, and post the output of tcpdump?

Comment: Weired !!!! what is this IP@ 62.201.153.142 for ?

Comment: # arp -na
? (172.30.149.92) à <incomplet> sur enp12s0
? (172.30.149.94) à <incomplet> sur enp12s0
# ip neighbor show
172.30.149.92 dev enp12s0  FAILED
172.30.149.94 dev enp12s0  FAILED

Comment: please try to ping the gateway while listening for arp packets. then repost the tcpdump output.

Comment: On your first tcpdump, we can see traffic from ip `172.30.150.115` which isn't supposed to be on the same network than you and, as a consequence, unreachable without using GW. Are you sure that your network patching is correct ? How do you get this IP/GW couple ? By DHCP ?

Comment: @binarym  the package you are referring to is a (valid Hot-Standby-Router-Protocol) multicast packet. The distribution of such packets depends on the switch configuration.

Comment: # tcpdump -v arp
tcpdump: listening on enp12s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:44:09.289931 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:10.314067 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell teltest, length 28
13:44:14.021038 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 62.201.153.150 tell 62.201.153.145, length 46
13:44:14.021065 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 62.201.153.142 tell 62.201.153.137, length 46

Comment: @Json: these comment-replies should **really** be in an [edit to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/556840/edit)! They're nearly impossible to read with the limited comment-formatting. Please take the commands and their output into your question so that it's all in one, easy-to-read place. Thank you!

Comment: Looks to me as if the gateway is in a different VLAN on the switch. Ask the switch admin for information about this. Hint: Your box IS in the same VLAN as 62.201.153.145/137

Comment: I'm not using a box at all. I'm just using my laptop. how can I delete it ?

Comment: Your laptop should be connected to the network via cable to a switch...?

Comment: To confirm you're trying to "hijack" a LAN using only tagged frames with VLAN and probably not allowing your "native" frames, please redo the tcpdump capture with also the `-e` option: it would then also display VLAN informations. difference of output example: `18:58:15.000720 ARP, Request who-has 192.0.2.11 tell 192.0.2.10, length 28` versus `18:58:09.880542 c2:c0:d4:fd:12:4d > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 46: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP, Request who-has 192.0.2.11 tell 192.0.2.10, length 28` (what matters will be those external IPs 62.201.x.y)

Comment: in fact, my laptop is directly connected to the router where many VLANs are assigned to the same port. I'm wondering whether this is the root cause: my laptop can't ping its default gateway because it doesn't know how to reach the proper VLAN....please confirm this finding. Is there a way to specify the right VLAN where the ping should be sent through? ( many VLANs are assigned to the same port in router)....looking forward to your reply.

Comment: This could well be the root cause. If you have a trunk port  (bundling several vlans) you need 802.1q-support on the laptop, and specify, which vlans you want to use. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan

Comment: Have you been able to solve that problem?

Comment: I'm still looking on how to add and tagg VLANs on ubuntu